# In Excel, can I create a formula that asks for my permission to enter an additional row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to do some calculations and I am having a hard time making a proper template.

So, this is a sample template that I have created.
Here, I have one "abc" asset and one "xyz" asset. The actual value of ABC is 5000 but the lending value is 2000. Similar can be said for XYZ.
Now, for example, if I add 12000 balance and secure it by one asset, it works fine. But I cannot add two assets to the same list.

Is there a way that I can do something where once I enter all the information in the bottom section, a pop up a window will ask me whether I want to add another asset for the same balance?

[image]

Any suggestions would help.

Comment: I‘m afraid Excel formula cannot get the result you need.

Comment: @Lee : I thought so too but I just wanted to make sure that I am not missing anything. So, is there any way to achieve this at all?

Comment: straight answer : "can I create a formula that asks for my permission to enter an additional row?" > Nope, not with just formulas. || "Can I make Excel asks for my permission to enter an specific additional row?" > Yes, via vba. || "Can I make Excel asks for my permission to edit a specific region of a sheet?" > Yes, use Review > Protect Sheet. (To ctrl which cell is editable/not-editable : cell > r-click > formatCell > protection 'lock/unlock' )

Comment: @p._phidot_ : Thank you sir. I think the vba thing might work. I will play around and see if I can it to work. Thank you for the suggestion once again. Much appreciated. :)